# Global variable in js files

Tags: javascript

I want one value to be accessible in all my tabs. I tried with hidden input, but it doesn't work. I tried with var x; in one of the js files, but the others can't access it. How to do it?

Comment: What do you mean by Tabs? Browser tabs?

Comment: @antyrat No. Website tabs. Like Home, About..

Comment: Do you have some example? You mean links to pages? Or this tabs is created using JS?

Comment: @Srcee Then you can't. JavaScript's scope cannot go beyond one page.

Comment: @Pranav I don't get error. It's just the variable is undefined in the other js file.

Comment: Place this variable in the top included javascript.

Comment: make a common JS; define global variable there and include this JS in each page .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > > I tried with var x; in one of the js files

are you sure u are declaring the variable globally? You also will have to import that JS to either the html pages you are using and put it above the other JS files. 
OR import it to each JS file <--i haven't tested this yet but im sure the other works

html5 document

```
<html>
<head>

<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JS/globalVar.js"></script>//file that contains global variables
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JS/java.js"></script>//file that needs global variables.
<script LANGUAGE="JavaScript" src="JS/otherJava.js"></script>//other JS files

<LINK REL=StyleSheet HREF="CSS/myCSS.css" TYPE="text/css" >//styling for html

</head>
```

Then in the JS file make sure you make the var global before all other functions

```
var GLOBAL1;
var GLOBAL2;
var GLOBAL3;

function main(){
      ...some code...
}
```